# How can I copy a file from one directory to another in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to copy a '.mp4' format file from my local folder named as backup to another directory `/media/c1`. For that i tried the below python code.

```
import shutil
fileList = os.listdir('/opt/backup/') 
for f in fileList:
  try:
    flocation = '/opt/backup/' + f
    fpath = '/media/c1/' + f
    shutil.copy2(flocation, fpath)
  except IOError:
    print("IOERROR")
```

While run this script, it throws below error.

```
The file path is :/media/c1/1027.mp4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 33, in <module>
    shutil.copy2(flocation, fpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 100, in copy2
    copystat(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/shutil.py", line 73, in copystat
    os.utime(dst, (st.st_atime, st.st_mtime))
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/media/c1/1027.mp4'
```

I need to copy all the media files which is located in backup folder and paste it into `/media/c1/` directory.

Comment: It's better to use `os.path.join('/opt/backup', f)` to create longer paths in Python. Your example code is not working code; `fp` and `filepath` are not defined.

Comment: Clearly you have a permissions problem in the source directory; an attempt is made to read the file properties of the source file and that fails. This is *not* a python problem.

Comment: What linux distro as re using? If you're copying a file somewhere outside of your home directory, you will most likely need to have admin permissions. Have you tried running your script using sudo/su?